# Run Greasemonkey on html files located on the local filesystem?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, local-files

I have an API documentation lying around on my Harddrive and to ease my workflow, I have written a simple script that modifies the page for my needs. I've developed it using FireBug on FireFox.

`@include`-ing webpages works correctly, but Greasemonkey does not seem to detect pages on the local file-system?

I would like to have an include like

```
// @include        *R13/Python*R13/*
```

Which should match for example

```
file:///Z:/Eigene%20Dateien/Cinema4D/Documentations/R13/Python%20R13/modules/c4d/index.html
```

But it is not recognized. How can I achieve that the userscript runs on local html files, too?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: maybe look at this: http://groups.google.com/group/greasemonkey-users/browse_thread/thread/ad67ee03ae92e3f0/1dc4075bdb53438a?pli=1

Comment: In Greasemonkey 4.10.0, I was able to match all files within the metadata block by setting `@match` to `file:///*`. To match mp4 and webm files I used: `file:///*.mp4` and `file:///*.webm`. To check if the specified files were being matched, I initially used `console.log` to output a simple message in the browser's console tab in the web developer window. Also, I didn't need to modify any configuration values within the browser to do this.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Since a couple of releases there are two new 'hidden' preferences:
>
> greasemonkey.aboutIsGreaseable
>   greasemonkey.fileIsGreaseable
>
> The
>   default value is "false".  If you want Greasemonkey to run on 
>   file:/// urls, you have to set the second one to "true" (in 
>   about:config).

Quoted from here:

http://groups.google.com/group/greasemonkey-users/browse_thread/thread/ad67ee03ae92e3f0/1dc4075bdb53438a

Comment: As of firefox 49.0 this seems to be extensions.greasemonkey.fileIsGreaseable, and you need to restart firefox after installing greasemonkey for the preference to appear

Answer (score 47):

## tampermonkey

If you're here for the same reason I am, which is -> looking for the [tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) equivalent, (and you're using Chrome)... go to Chrome Preferences -> Extensions, aka chrome://extensions/, and you'll see  **Allow access to file URLs**

[image: Allow access to file URLs]