# Basic method to Add html content to the page with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Is there a Greasemonkey method to append basic HTML content to the end of a page right after the `<body>` tag, or right before it ends?

I found before/after methods but I need to know names of elements which may change page to page..

Comment: use `document.body.insertBefore(newElement,document.body.firstChild)` to put something at the start

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The quick and dirty way:  Please only use `innerHTML` for brand-***new*** content.

```
var newHTML         = document.createElement ('div');
newHTML.innerHTML   = '             \
    <div id="gmSomeID">             \
        <p>Some paragraph</p>       \
        etc.                        \
    </div>                          \
';

document.body.appendChild (newHTML);
```

---

---

**A complete script** showing the somewhat better jQuery way (and with new, ECMAScript 6, multiline string):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
//--- The @grant directive is used to restore the proper sandbox.

$("body").append ( `
    <div id="gmSomeID">
        <p>Some paragraph</p>
        etc.
    </div>
` );
```

---

---

Both methods will place the new content like this:

```html
<!-- NEW STUFF INSERTED HERE -->
</body>
```

Which is a good place for it.

Even though the HTML is at the *end* of the page, you can use CSS to *display* it anywhere with something like:

```
GM_addStyle ( "                         \
    #gmSomeID {                         \
        position:       fixed;          \
        top:            0px;            \
        left:           0px;            \
    }                                   \
" );
```

Comment: oh wait, that works by appending a new element to the end of the body. Looks nice despite the slightly misleading naming. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Yes, the question title and text was a little contradictory.  Edited to clear up.  Appending new content to the `<body>` is the best default location.

Comment: Yes, when I first skim-read this answer I didn't realize `newHTML` was actually an element that serves as container for the new html instead of a plain html string, I noticed that right after though. Your answer is quite clear +1 `:P`

Comment: You should use Content Script Injection https://wiki.greasespot.net/Content_Script_Injection which is cleaner and will also prevent errors when using regular expressions if you forgot to double escape a slash character https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40191536/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got

Comment: @baptx, that is for javascript and will not work at all in this case.  This question is about HTML.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to have to muck around with having to escape your multi line html - you can put your HTML in local files, and load it using `GM_getResourceText`. Make sure you have [enabled your Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey to use local files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931115/run-greasemonkey-on-html-files-located-on-the-local-filesystem)

eg:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Tamper Test
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        file:///C:/david/sandbox/tampermonkey/tamper.html
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @resource html      file:///C:/david/sandbox/tampermonkey/foo.html
// @resource style     file:///C:/david/sandbox/tampermonkey/style.css
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// @grant  GM_getResourceText
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {
    'use strict';

    $("body").append('<div id = "dwj-tamper">new content from tamper script</div>');  

    GM_addStyle(GM_getResourceText("style"));    
    $("body").append(GM_getResourceText("html"));

})();
```

This solution is fine if the tamperscript is for yourself only. You can similarly save the resource online. For example:

```
// @resource pastebin http://pastebin.com/raw/9WfbN24i

//...

 $("body").append(GM_getResourceText("pastebin"));
```

also works

[image]