# Save button with count greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey

i want to add an save button with a counter
i wrote a script but its not work with greasemonkey

```
<button type="submit" id="save" value="Save">Save</button>

<p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
var button = document.getElementById("save");
var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");
function loadStats(){
if(window.localStorage.getItem('count')){
count = window.localStorage.getItem('count')
display.innerHTML = count;
} else {
window.localStorage.setItem('count', 0)
} //Checks if data has been saved before so Count value doesnt become null.
}
window.localStorage.setItem("on_load_counter", count);
button.onclick = function(){
count++;
window.localStorage.setItem("count", count)
display.innerHTML = count;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add html elements with javascript since Greasemonkey is intended to run scripts over web pages.

See [Basic method to Add html content to the page with Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249712/basic-method-to-add-html-content-to-the-page-with-greasemonkey)