# how to append tag to window reference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jquery/javascript, how can you open up a popup window, and then add a script tag to it? Something like:

```
var a = window.open("www.mypage.com");
a.append("<script type='text/javascript' src='file.js'></script>");
```

Note: I cannot modify the code of `"www.mypage.com"`.

How can this be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much this is possible, for security reasons.

If I could append script to a page without you knowing I could do all sorts of things, including capturing the keys you press when you log in to your email, for instance.

Comment: In terms of security whats the differnce between doing this and just loading an iframe, and then using jquery to insert the script node in the iframe?

Comment: Good question, I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible based on security regulations as per Apache.  If it were allowed, you could even penetrate a banking site! But, this technically can be done but via greasemonkey scripting yourFile.user.js.

More details:  [Run Greasemonkey on html files located on the local filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931115/run-greasemonkey-on-html-files-located-on-the-local-filesystem)

Tutorial: http://userscripts.org/about/installing

Comment: But can't you do the same thing by using an iframe, and then using jquery to insert a script in the iframe?